# Disable Windows Defender Firewall pop up for a target folder

Tags: windows, firewall, windows-firewall

I'm encountering an issue with the Windows Defender Firewall every time I compile and run my Go program. It seems that the program's use of sockets is triggering the firewall each time a new version of the program is compiled and run as a new `.exe` file.

Here is what's currently happening :

1. I make some changes to my code
2. I compile, thus a new `.exe` is created
3. Run the new `.exe`
4. I'm getting annoyed by the Windows Security Alert popup

[image: Windows Defender Firewall notification at compilation]

From my understanding, we can't set up a firewall rule exception for a whole folder, but is that really the case? I could simply disable the firewall but that's not really a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

> [...] we can't set up a firewall rule exception for a whole folder,

Yes. You cannot set up a rule for alle binaries in a folder.

> I could simply disable the firewall but that's not really a good idea.

You could simply add a rule for your (TCP/UDP) port.